# Using capture and mocks to unit test a class

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

I am trying to unit test the following class:

```
class UserProfileDetailsAnalyticUseCaseImp @Inject constructor(private val analyticsProvider: AnalyticsProvider) : UserProfileDetailsAnalyticUseCase {
    override fun execute(cdsCustomer: CDSCustomer) {
        with(analyticsProvider) {
            log(AnalyticEvent.UserId(cdsCustomer.id.toString()))
            log(AnalyticEvent.UserEmail(cdsCustomer.email))
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my unit test:

```
class UserProfileDetailsAnalyticUseCaseImpTest {

    private lateinit var userProfileDetailsAnalyticUseCaseImp: UserProfileDetailsAnalyticUseCaseImp
    private val analyticsProviders: AnalyticsProvider = mock()


    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        userProfileDetailsAnalyticUseCaseImp = UserProfileDetailsAnalyticUseCaseImp(analyticsProviders)
    }

    @Test
    fun `should send analytic event`() {
        // Arrange
        val cdsCustomer = CDSCustomer(
            id = Random.nextInt(0, 100000),
            email = UUID.randomUUID().toString())

        val userIdCapture= argumentCaptor<AnalyticEvent.UserId>()
        val userEmailCapture= argumentCaptor<AnalyticEvent.UserEmail>()

        // Act
        userProfileDetailsAnalyticUseCaseImp.execute(cdsCustomer)

        // Assert
        verify(analyticsProviders, atLeastOnce()).log(userIdCapture.capture())
        verify(analyticsProviders, atLeastOnce()).log(userEmailCapture.capture())
    
        assertThat(userIdCapture.firstValue.userId).isEqualTo(cdsCustomer.id.toString())
        assertThat(userEmailCapture.firstValue.email).isEqualTo(cdsCustomer.email)
    }
}
```

The error I get is the following:

```
AnalyticEvent$UserId cannot be cast to AnalyticEvent$UserEmail
```

I am suspecting that because class under test is creating a new object for each `log` method they will not be the same for the verified methods in the unit test

i.e `log(AnalyticEvent.UserId(cdsCustomer.id.toString()))`

As a new `AnaltyicEvent.UserId` will be created and just for the same `AnalyticProvider` mock

Many thanks for any suggetions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [the documentation](https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) of `ArgumentCaptor` we can read that:

> This utility class *doesn't do any type checks*. The generic
> signatures are only there to avoid casting in your code.

Moreover **CapturingMatcher** which is used for collecting captured arguments has a method which matches all objects:

```
public boolean matches(Object argument) {
    return true;
}
```

It means that it is normal behaviour and even when we specify concrete type of captor it will record all arguments passed.
Of course all these arguments have to inherit from the same base class because in other case `capture` method will cause compilation error.

So, both your captors record two arguments.

To fix class cast exception for your test you can assert **secondValue** for email.

```
assertThat(userEmailCapture.secondValue.email).isEqualTo(cdsCustomer.email)
```

You can also stop using argument captors and simply verify invocations of `log` method.

```
verify(analyticsProviders).log(AnalyticEvent.UserId(cdsCustomer.id.toString()))
verify(analyticsProviders).log(AnalyticEvent.UserEmail(cdsCustomer.email))
```

Comment: One issue is that a new `AnalyticEvent.UserId(...)` will be created in the verify method. Which will be different in the production code. As we are creating a new `AnalyticEvent.UserId(..)` So when I run the test will fail.  Wanted `AnalyticEvent$UserId@446a5cd0` and actual `AnalyticEvent$UserId@3b663b98`

Comment: Mockito is using `equals` method during verification. When your AnalyticEvents are data classes or have properly implemented `equals` method then it doesn't matter if it is the same instance of the object. Test should pass

Comment: My `AnalyticEvent` class is a sealed class. Is there any another way to test this without overriding the equals method in that class?

Comment: In case when you `AnalyticEvent` class is sealed then your `UserId` and `UserEmail` should be data classes extending it and you don't have to worry about `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

`data class UserEmail(val email: String) : AnalyticEvent()`

Comment: This looks like a correct answer, and the data class idea/workaround should work fine.